# Identifying and formatting XML String to readable format in XMLParser

Tags: swift, macos, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, xmldocument

I am working in Swift and I have a set of Data that I can encode as a String like this:

```
<CONTAINER><Creator type="NSNull"/><Category type="NSNull"/><UMID type="NSArray"><CHILD>d1980b265cbd415c90f5d5f04efcb5df</CHILD><CHILD>7e0252c137c249fc92bd0f844effe27f</CHILD></UMID><Channels type="NSNumber">1</Channels></CONTAINER>
```

I am looking for a way to format this string as XML with indents so I can use XMLParser to properly read through it, which it currently does not. I imagine NSNull is when the object is empty, I just haven't seen this format so I don't know what to search for.  Could it be closer to a Dictionary object? If so I'd be happy to format it as that as well.

I've also tried to create a XMLDocument from the data, but it doesn't fix the format.

EDIT:

I wanted to add a bit more information to help clarify what I am trying to do.  This string above is derived from an encrypted piece of metadata from a file. In my code I identify the chunk of data that is encrypted, then decrypt it, and then convert that data to a string.  It's worth noting that the string ends up having null characters in between each valid character, but I strip those out and end up with this string.

Copying this string into an XML Validator confirms it is valid XML.  What is confusing to me is it's format, in which it has Object types such as NSNull and NSNumber.  My post was originally hoping to identify this type of format.  It seems like more than just XML.

In response to some of the comments, I have used XML Parser delegate with other XML strings and have a basic understanding of how it works.  I should have originally mentioned that and instead said that XML Parser does not recognize any of these elements or strings within them.

UPDATE:

The issue ended up being the null characters in between each valid character.  Stripping those out and then running it through XML Parser worked great.  Thanks all.

Comment: XMLParser doesn’t care about indentation. This is probably invalid XML in some way or another. I would suggest formatting/indenturing it yourself I’m a code editor, and pasting it into one of the many available XML validators online, to see if it’s malformed.

Comment: “Could it be closer to a Dictionary object? If so I'd be happy to format it as that as well.” Not sure what you mean by “dictionary object”, but dictionaries are unjust associative data structures. They don’t have a format. One can serialized a dictionary in many ways, such as in JSON, XML or YAML, but that doesn’t really have anything to do with the dictionary

Comment: You can use XMLParser but you have to define and write your own logic to handle the different "type" values

Comment: Could you please post the code what you tried.

Comment: WAYRTTD? What does 'properly read through it' mean to you? If you achieve that, what would you do next?  I'm asking because "An XMLParser notifies its delegate about the items (elements, attributes, CDATA blocks, comments, and so on) that it encounters as it processes an XML document. It does not itself do anything with those parsed items except report them. It also reports parsing errors."  So "properly", from the point of view of the parser, could mean "report a parsing error".

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the comments and details. I added some more info.  According to online XML validators it is valid XML.  In terms of my comment of about the dictionary, I just meant that it resembles a NSDictionary structure.  I'm not familiar with the process of dictionary serialization so I'll need to look into that.